# Will you explain this code to me?

Tags: javascript

This snippet is from FreeCodeCamp Seek And Destroy. I don't understand the function passed into the filter. All other steps make sense to me besides that. Would you please break this down to me? I'd appreciate the help.

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        args.splice(0, 1);
        return arr.filter(function(element) {
          return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
       });
    }
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What don't you understand about it? A return statement? The `===` operator? The `indexOf` method? The `args` variable?

Comment: I don't understand the return statement in the filter.

Answer (score 0):

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
        //first the function get all the argument  pass in it
        var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
        // it delete the first argument that is the name of the element called
        args.splice(0, 1);
        // then it return a filter function that is another function that return a boolean true the element is display false it is hide
        return arr.filter(function(element) {
         // this boolean match to the element is present as argument or not
          return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
       });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In return statement, code it returning a list of items/numbers that do not match given number `element`. `filter takes a callback that returns true or false. and filter calls that callback for each item and finally returns list of those items that pass that condition.

```
arr.filter(function(element) {
      return args.indexOf(element) === -1;
   });
```